# Composer : remove dependency from package without rm'ing in the vendor package

Tags: json, dependencies, package, composer-php

I install a package with dependencies I don't want in the vendor folder :

`composer require author/package`

Then I do a :

`composer remove otherauthor/otherpackage1 otherauthor2/otherpackage2 ...`

and it does nothing.

If I manually install all the unused package, editing the composer.json file, then install the main package I want : `author/package`, and then do the : `composer remove otherauthor/otherpackage1 otherauthor2/otherpackage2 ...`

it does nothing too as the composer.json file has been rewritten without the unused dependencies I don't want, as they are dependencies of the main package.

How can I do it with the composer command line tool without doing a `rm -rf` in the vendor package ?

Comment: Where do you want the dependencies? That package obviously needs them, and that's the reason you cannot remove them because they are no direct dependencies you actively installed.

Comment: I have thought again about the way the package should be installed, and I think I was wrong willing to remove dependencies.

Remove is logically for packages, not for dependencies. Ok !